# inAppPurchases empty products array

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, itunes, storekit

On iTunes connect I have created app and some non-consumable products. Its my first product with in-app purchases and I have not uploaded binary yet. Bundle Id of app in xCode and itunes are match. Product Id is com.xxx.product1. Here is sample code:

```
_productsRequest = [[SKProductsRequest alloc] initWithProductIdentifiers:_productIdentifiers];
_productsRequest.delegate = self;
[_productsRequest start];
```

in

```
- (void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse *)response {

NSLog(@"PRODUCTS:\n%@", response.products);
}
```

I have empty array... But all products id in `response.invalidProductIdentifiers` identifiers are correct at itunes. And but if I create free product on itunes (ex.: com.xxx.freeProduct1)
It's returning my product description.
Why I cant get non-consumable products? Thanks..

Comment: all u need to do is reconfirm the product-ids strings from itunesconnect

Comment: Already did this.. product id matches..

Comment: re-check ur appid in info.plist

Comment: I Have 2 warnings in my product: Note:
You do not currently have a iOS Paid Apps contract in effect. If this In-App Purchase was submitted with your app, then your app will not be available on the App Store until your contract goes into effect. Legal, Admin, and Finance users can go to the Contracts, Tax, and Banking module in iTunes Connect to view your contract status.
Your first In-App Purchase(s) must be submitted with a new app version. Select them from the In-App Purchases section of the Version Details page and then click Ready to Upload Binary.

Comment: Is this necessary for my test app and products?

Comment: I am facing same problem , with same messages in iTunes account. Any help please???

Comment: Kamal Sharma, issue was in client iTunes account. Client must have banking, tax and other contracts with apple to have such notifications.

Comment: hi @LightNight did you solve the problem? can you share the answer?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly to answer the comment about not having an iOS Paid Apps contract, you need to put one into effect so that Apple can pay you any profits you make from the App Store. Also, the text "You first In-App-Purchase(s) must be submitted..." does not affect testing In App Purchases. You can still test purchase them and receive product information without clicking ready to upload binary. So back to the original question, sometimes it takes up to a day or so for any changes in iTunes Connect to work their way through Apple's systems. Because you do not have an iOS Paid Apps contract in effect, the App Store is probably pretending you do not have any paid products for your app because you are not allowed to sell any for money. Get the contract into effect and wait a day or so and things will probably fix themselves.